# How would I break out of a function inside of a while loop in python?

Tags: python, function, loops, while-loop, break

I cannot break out of this function inside of a while loop.

This is the error message

> SyntaxError: 'break' outside loop

Code:

```
import random
 
while True:

    def roll (min, max):
        num = random.randrange(min, max)
        print(num)
        if num == 9:
            break

    roll(1,10)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the trick

```py
import random
 
while True:

    def roll (min, max):
        num = random.randrange(min, max)
        print(num)
        return num 

    num = roll(1,10)
    if num == 9:
        break
```